# Excel: Nesting two Nested IF statements inside one IF statement depending on Dropdown Box

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

I have 2 Nested IF Statements..

`=IF($B3=$K$3,DATE(YEAR(D3)+$L$3,MONTH(D3)+$M$3,DAY(D3)),IF($B3=$K$4,DATE(YEAR(D3)+$L$4,MONTH(D3)+$M$4,DAY(D3)),IF($B3=$K$5,DATE(YEAR(D3)+$L$5,MONTH(D3)+$M$5,DAY(D3)),IF($B3=$K$6,DATE(YEAR(D3)+$L$6,MONTH(D3)+$M$6,DAY(D3)),""))))`

and

`=IF($C3=$O$3,DATE(YEAR(D3)+$P$3,MONTH(D3)+$Q$3,DAY(D3)),IF($C3=$O$4,DATE(YEAR(D3)+$P$4,MONTH(D3)+$Q$4,DAY(D3)),IF($C3=$O$5,DATE(YEAR(D3)+$P$5,MONTH(D3)+$Q$5,DAY(D3)),"")))`

which work as required in two separate columns.  What I would like is to Nest them again so that depending on the choice made from a Data Validation dropbox (Choice 1 or Choice 2, in the following) it either displays the date calculated from the first Choice, or from the second.  This is what I have, but I can't get it to work.  I think I need an OR in there, but I don't know where, as there are so many IFs already.

`=IF($I$2=”Choice1”,IF($B3=$K$3,DATE(YEAR(D3)+$L$3,MONTH(D3)+$M$3,DAY(D3)),IF($B3=$K$4,DATE(YEAR(D3)+$L$4,MONTH(D3)+$M$4,DAY(D3)),IF($B3=$K$5,DATE(YEAR(D3)+$L$5,MONTH(D3)+$M$5,DAY(D3)),IF($B3=$K$6,DATE(YEAR(D3)+$L$6,MONTH(D3)+$M$6,DAY(D3)))),IF($I$2=”Choice2”,IF($C3=$O$3,DATE(YEAR(D3)+$P$3,MONTH(D3)+$Q$3,DAY(D3)),IF($C3=$O$4,DATE(YEAR(D3)+$P$4,MONTH(D3)+$Q$4,DAY(D3)),IF($C3=$O$5,DATE(YEAR(D3)+$P$5,MONTH(D3)+$Q$5,DAY(D3))),""))))))`

If it was just one column of dates I can use this..

`=IF($I$2="Choice 1",$E4, IF($I$2="Choice 2",$F4,""))`

with a couple of helper columns, but I could have as many as 10, which would require 20 helper columns on a spreadsheet that's already 70 odd columns wide, which I'd rather avoid if possible.  I've done this on a test worksheet, rather than mess about with the original for now.

**EDIT**  Additional information as requested.  (Edited to generic terms as it's a work item)

I have these columns

[image]

and using the following dropdown..

[image]

would like the date in "Choice 1 OR 2 Increase" to update depending on the selection of either "Choice 1" or Choice 2" information chosen from either of the two sets of Category dropdowns..

[image][image]

This formula takes the information from the first date dropdown and correctly calculates the new date..
`=IF($B3=$K$3,DATE(YEAR(D3)+$L$3,MONTH(D3)+$M$3,DAY(D3)),IF($B3=$K$4,DATE(YEAR(D3)+$L$4,MONTH(D3)+$M$4,DAY(D3)),IF($B3=$K$5,DATE(YEAR(D3)+$L$5,MONTH(D3)+$M$5,DAY(D3)),IF($B3=$K$6,DATE(YEAR(D3)+$L$6,MONTH(D3)+$M$6,DAY(D3)),""))))`

with Category 1 - 4, in that order, being the four date sections of this formula.

This formula takes the information from the second date dropdown and correctly calculates the new date..
`=IF($C3=$O$3,DATE(YEAR(D3)+$P$3,MONTH(D3)+$Q$3,DAY(D3)),IF($C3=$O$4,DATE(YEAR(D3)+$P$4,MONTH(D3)+$Q$4,DAY(D3)),IF($C3=$O$5,DATE(YEAR(D3)+$P$5,MONTH(D3)+$Q$5,DAY(D3)),"")))`

with Category 5-7, in that order being the three date sections of this formula.

Both formulas work correctly when used independently of each other to populate individual columns, and a third column can be used to get the date required (using the dates already provided separately in two "helper" columns) using the following formula..

`=IF($I$2="Choice1",$E3, IF($I$2="Choice2",$F3,""))`

[image]

What I would like is to be able to combine the actions of both of the above formulas somehow, so that by using the Choice 1/Choice 2 dropdown (Pic 2), it calculates the date depending on the choice in that dropdown box, and also the other two dropdown boxes (Pics 3 + 4) and populates the "Choice 1 OR 2 Increase" column (Pic 1)

If I was only using this one example, I'd just use the helper columns but there will be several, and the sheet is around 70 columns wide already.  Combining (at least the actions of) these two formulas into one, will save a lot of extra columns.

I hope that's the information you require..

Thanks

Liam

Comment: "can't get it to work" is not helpful information. Suggest you back up and describe the problem that you think these complicated IF formulas, nested, would be the solution.  So called [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Post an example of your data and desired outcomes; see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Ron.. apologies.  I'll edit the post this morning when I can, and let you know when it's done.   Thanks

Comment: Edited for clearer information.

Answer (score 0):

I would set things up differently, and use a different formula.

Since your Categories and Choices do not overlap, I would combine all the categories into a single table.

eg:

[image]

Since both `Years` and `Months` can have a varying number of days, I'd suggest using `EDATE` for the additions.

I also used a Named Range for the `Choice` dropdown,

[image]

and a `Table` for the Category table.

Doing that, you can use this formula (assuming your data table is in `A1:Cn`)

```
=EDATE(C2,VLOOKUP(INDEX($A2:$B$5,1,MATCH(Choice,$A$1:$B$1,0)),Category,2,FALSE)*12 + VLOOKUP(INDEX($A2:$B$5,1,MATCH(Choice,$A$1:$B$1,0)),Category,3,FALSE))
```

The formula

- `MATCH` decides which column of category choice to use
- `VLOOKUP` to return the appropriate years and months
- `EDATE(Date, years*12 + months)`

If you prefer to use your method of adding datevalues, you can apply the same methodology:

```
=DATE(YEAR(C2)+VLOOKUP(INDEX($A2:$B$5,1,MATCH(Choice,$A$1:$B$1,0)),Category,2,FALSE),MONTH(C2)+VLOOKUP(INDEX($A2:$B$5,1,MATCH(Choice,$A$1:$B$1,0)),Category,3,FALSE),DAY(C2))
```

Note that the two methods can give different results depending on the day of the month, and whether the end month has the same number of days as the start month.

eg:

```
    31 January 2020 + 1 month --> 29 Feb 2020 vs 02 Mar 2020
    31 January 2020 + 3 month --> 30 Apr 2020 vs 01 May 2020
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for such an indepth answer.. I'm going to spend a bit of time reading through it now..  :)